# Redirecting a mobile user to a desktop version

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, mobile, detect

I have a Wordpress website that is using device detection to redirect users browsing on their mobile device to a specific page using the following:

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location = "176.32.230.17/domain.co.uk/m";
}
</script>
```

This code currently sits on the homepage template for domain.co.uk. Just after the opening body tag. The detection and redirection works well however, I need to provide a link back to the desktop version of the website on that mobile page. So just a simple link:

```
<a href="http://176.32.230.17/domain.co.uk/?ref=desktop">Link back to desktop website</a>
```

This works in that it directs the user back to the domain.co.uk address however, because the placement of the detection/redirection code is on the homepage template on domain.co.uk, the user gets redirected back to the mobile version. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need someway to convey the fact that the user has already been redirected once. If you're using PHP, you could have a conditional redirection using a GET variable. If you're just using Javascript, maybe use a cookie. HTML5 also supports some kind of data storage as well, but I'm not familiar with that.

EDIT: Actually, you could just tack on a GET variable to the address and not even use PHP. Just get the address using `window.location.href` and see if the variable is set using Javascript only.

EDIT2: Too much got put in the comments, so let me put this here. The link should be changed to:

```
<a href="http://176.32.230.17/domain.co.uk/?ref=desktop#redirected">Link back to desktop website</a>
```

And the redirection code can be changed to:

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
        !window.location.href.contains("#redirected") ) {
    window.location = "176.32.230.17/domain.co.uk/m";
}
</script>
```

Comment: How would I go about using either the JS method or the PHP method? I'm not too sure how to do either... WHich one is best to implement?

Comment: Well, first tell us, are you using PHP or not?

Comment: Well i'm using Wordpress so I could use PHP. I'm open to whichever method is best to be honest

Comment: I would do something like this: redirect the user to website/?ref=desktop&already_redirected=true. Then, in Javascript, get the window.location.href variable and search it. If it has already_redirected=true in it, don't redirect a second time.

Comment: You say 'get the window.location.href variable and search it' how do I do this?

Comment: window.lcation.href is just a string. You might want to take a look at the Javascript string functions if you're unsure how to search one. The contains method would be the best choice.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods

Comment: Thanks for the code but unfortunately the redirect doesn't work at all now. Is the if statement saying, if its any of these device AND does not contain the hashtag '#redirected', redirect to the mobile page?

Comment: The extra if clause shouldn't affect anything if you don't add the tag. You likely have a script error. Use the debug console to find out.